# How do I scale a polygon in Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I have a polygon,

```
 X = 100
 Y = 100
 A = 20
 B = 20
 pygame.draw.polygon(screen,red,[(B+X,A+Y),(-B+X,A+Y),(X,Y)])#(X,Y,Z)
```

**how do I scale it from the origin point (X,Y)?**

```
this ->
  X(0,0)
 /\
/  \
----Z(2,-2)
Y(-2,-2)
should become this -->
 X(0,0)
/\
--Z(1,-1)
Y(-1,-1)
```

But **it appears Pygame does not have a method of scaling polygons**
 **without just changing their points**, so how would I go about 
doing this? **The polygon can flip itself at any given time** and 
therefore changing the points is not a good solution, as it leads 
to the polygon growing again once it has been flipped.

Comment: you could draw on `Surface()`, rescale `Surface` and blit `Surface` on `screen` but it will  give worse image. It is better to recalculate points A,B,X,Y.

Comment: I'd actually considered that before, but abandoned the idea for that very reason. I suppose it'd actually make more sense to make one LARGE polygon and scale it down instead if I was going to do that, however even then that'd probably be resource intensive don't you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using matrix it could be done better but I use normal methods

I have

```
X = 100
Y = 100
A = 20
B = 20
```

and points

```
x = (X,Y)
y = (X+B,Y+A)
z = (X-B,Y+A)

print(x,y,z)

(100, 100) (120, 120) (80, 120)
```

origin is point `x`

```
origin = x[0], x[1]
```

I move all points so using `origin` so `oringi (`x`) will be`(0,0)`

```
x1 = x[0]-origin[0], x[1]-origin[1] 
y1 = y[0]-origin[0], y[1]-origin[1] 
z1 = z[0]-origin[0], z[1]-origin[1] 

print(x1,y1,z1)

(0, 0) (20, 20) (-20, 20)
```

As I see you need scale 1/2

```
scale = 1/2

x1 = x1[0]*scale, x1[1]*scale
y1 = y1[0]*scale, y1[1]*scale
z1 = z1[0]*scale, z1[1]*scale

print(x1,y1,z1)

(0.0, 0.0) (10.0, 10.0) (-10.0, 10.0)
```

Finally I move all back

```
x = x1[0]+origin[0], x1[1]+origin[1] 
y = y1[0]+origin[0], y1[1]+origin[1] 
z = z1[0]+origin[0], z1[1]+origin[1] 

print(x,y,z)

(100.0, 100.0) (110.0, 110.0) (90.0, 110.0)
```

And this is new polygon

```
(100.0, 100.0) (110.0, 110.0) (90.0, 110.0)
```

---

In your example you could also rescale only `A` `B`

```
scale = 1/2

X = 100
Y = 100
A = 20 * scale
B = 20 * scale
```

And

```
(B+X,A+Y),(-B+X,A+Y),(X,Y)
```

gives the same values

```
(110.0, 110.0), (90.0, 110.0), (100, 100)
```

Comment: I don't understand what x[0] and x[1] reference as I don't have any array up there for those terms and neither do you. in fact I don't have any list arrays in my question. Do you mean x[0] as (B+X)
and x[1] as (A+Y)?

Comment: `[]` is used also with tuples like `x = (X,Y), y = (X+B,Y+A), z = (X-B,Y+A)` Every point has two values `(x, y)` and using `x[0]` I get first value from this tuple, etc. If I have `x = (X,Y)` then `x[0]` gives me value `X`, `x[1]` gives value `Y`